# MySQL Workbench giving Error 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I'm toying around with MySQL Workbench, using its tools to create my database. When attempting to forward engineer the database, I keep getting this error.

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-01-01,
  `PlateNum` CHAR(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ABCDEFG',
  `CellPhone` INT(10) U' at line 9
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `MetalDelivery`.`Drivers`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MetalDelivery`.`Drivers` (
          `DriverID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `FName` CHAR(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'First',
          `LName` CHAR(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Last',
          `Sex` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M',
          `DOB` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT 1900-01-01,
          `PlateNum` CHAR(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ABCDEFG',
          `CellPhone` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 5550000000,
          PRIMARY KEY (`DriverID`))
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed
```

In the SQL script preview, it does show a semicolon after InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of date needs to be specified as if a string:

```
 `DOB` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01'
```

It's also worth expanding this schema a little. Names are frequently over 12 letters long. `VARCHAR(255)` is a good default for "string" fields.

You may find that these defaults are a huge mistake. It's possible someone's actual last name is "Last" in which case it's like they're using a default, or they simply don't have a last name. `NULL` values serve a purpose, so embrace them.

Comment: That did the trick! It threw me that it added the single quotes for my CHAR default values, but not for that.

Comment: Anything that's not a simple number or a function call needs quotes with the exception of things like "entity names" such as tables, columns or databases. That was being parsed as "1900 minus 1 minus 1" which is not something you can do in a default.